# Cron Authentification Digest Symfony

Tags: symfony, cron

My website is on an Infomaniak cloud server.

I can create a cron task with Authentification Digest.

So I made a Method "updateAction()" that update my database.

If I run this method in my browser (http://site1.com/update/), then I authenticate with my username and password. (It works and the database is updated)

I create a cronjob in my "Infomaniak Cloud Server" with Digest Authentication and the URL : http://site1.com/update/

I obtain this mail notification :

---

Cron name : Update

Date : 19/01/2018 16:51:18

Url : https://site1.com/update/

Result : OK

Detail : 204

Reponse : No response

---

So, the HTTP response is "204 : No content"
And my database is not updated.

Could you help me ?

**So the solution is :**

```
$url="http://site1.com/update/";
define('USERNAME','user');
define('PASSWORD','12345');
$ch=null;
try 
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, USERNAME . ":" . PASSWORD);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    $resp = curl_exec($ch);
}
catch(Exception $ex) 
{

}
```

Comment: You are using cron to do http requests? Their cron system doesn't allow you to access the console?

Comment: No, I can only run url to execute method.

Comment: I understand why it didn't work. I called a route in my controller folder. The solution is to create a script in the "web" folder that call the route with curl or with file_get_content()

Comment: that's seems very insecure as everyone can call those scripts. Be very carefull. Happy you found a solution anyway

Comment: I add my solution above, is it realy unsecured ? Thanks everybody for your help !

Comment: If your curl script is on Infomaniak configuration it's ok.If it's inside the web directory it could be reach by anyone!